# Issue while executing shell script through jenkins

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, groovy, sh

I am trying to run a shell script through jenkins pipeline. When I run it manually it works fine. But in same machine when I am execute it through jenkins file it is failing.

Jenkins file :-

```
if ("${BRANCH_NAME}".startsWith("users"))
        {
        node ('linux')
        {
            stage('run groovy script')
            {
            stdout = sh(script: '"$MyWorkSpaceLinux/planning/build/jdocgroovy.sh" ${BUILD_NUMBER}', returnStdout : true)
            println("running groovy stdout################ " + stdout + " ####################")
            }
        }
        }
```

Below is the error:

```
javadoc: error - cannot read jdocgroovyfiles_ux.dat (No such file or directory)
cp: cannot stat `groovy-examples.html': No such file or directory
Emptying out Javadoc folder
Generatig Javadoc files
```

Below is the shell script:-

```
export PLANNING_HOME=/scratch/pqsharma/jenkins/workspace/Planning_develop/planning/HspJS
export JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/

build_no=${1}
echo Emptying out Javadoc folder
mkdir "/net/slcnas502.us.oracle.com/export/EPM_Planning/PlanningDev/Buzz/tmp_pre_rel/Planning/builds/develop/${build_no}/src/javadocgroovy"


echo Generatig Javadoc files
"${JDK_HOME}/bin/javadoc" -classpath ${PLANNING_HOME}/lib/Jersey/jersey-core.jar -sourcepath "${PLANNING_HOME}/src" -windowtitle "Oracle Enterprise Performance Management Cloud, Groovy Rules" -header "Oracle Enterprise Performance Management Cloud, Groovy Rules Java API Reference" -bottom "Copyright &copy; 2017, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved." -overview groovy-overview.html -public -nodeprecated -d "/net/slcnas502.us.oracle.com/export/EPM_Planning/PlanningDev/Buzz/tmp_pre_rel/Planning/builds/develop/${build_no}/src/javadocgroovy" @jdocgroovyfiles_ux.dat

cp groovy-examples.html "/net/slcnas502.us.oracle.com/export/EPM_Planning/PlanningDev/Buzz/tmp_pre_rel/Planning/builds/develop/${build_no}/src/javadocgroovy"
```

Someone kindly help me to understand why am I not able to execute it through jenkins file

Comment: Looks like you need the full path to groovy-examples.html in your cp command.

Comment: I think his is the main error "javadoc: error - cannot read jdocgroovyfiles_ux.dat (No such file or directory)
"

Comment: Yeah. Same issue with that file as well. Full path required.

Comment: but when I run the same script manually I didn't face the issue. @jdocgroovyfiles_ux.dat, here where to add the path. file name is jdocgroovyfiles_ux.dat

Comment: Did you run the script manually from the same directory as the files?

Comment: yes. getting the same error again. javadoc: error - cannot read /scratch/pqsharma/jenkins/workspace/Planning_develop/planning/jdocgroovyfiles_ux.dat (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is Jenkins was expecting full paths to be given for all the files. After giving paths it started working fine.